# Line+symbol plotstyle in Plot function

Tags: plotting

Is there anyway to plot an analytical function using symbols + lines rather than only lines?

Something like the plot shown in this figure:

[image]

Comment: Lookup `Dashing` and `PlotMarkers`, and if you want help always provide a code sample to work with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
f[x_] := x^2;
Show[Plot[f[x], 
  {x, 0, 5},
  PlotStyle -> Dashed],
ListPlot[Table[{x, f[x]}, 
  {x, 0, 5, .5}],
  PlotStyle -> Red]
```

Comment: Does it mean that ‘ListPlot’ has to be used to obtain symbols/markers? Is there any ‘Plot’ only solution?